# What is the meaning of 没 in 有啥推荐没?

Tags: grammar, meaning, yes-no-questions

有啥推荐没?

What is the meaning of 没 here in this sentence?

Can I put 吗 instead of 没 here?

Comment: As for your second question, yes, you could replace 没 with 吗 in that sentence, it would still be grammatical (actually I kinda prefer it with 吗）

Answer (score 1):

有啥推荐没? （有啥推荐吗?）
Are there any suggestions, or not?

I would say it's a kind of short-speak for:

关于这个问题，有没有什么推荐吗？
Concerning this problem, are there any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

有啥推荐没? （有啥推荐吗?） is informal and oral.

You also can use 的 at the end of this kind of sentences.

> 有啥推薦**的**？ 有**沒**啥推薦**的**？

e.g.

附近的餐廳有啥推薦的？

附近有沒啥推薦的餐廳？

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

吃饭没？ Had dinner or not?

听见我没？ Can hear me or not?

看了电影没 Watched that movie or not?

the expectation of this question is to get an answer of "yes" or "no"

now you know what is that "没" mean

Comment: Thanks, that’s what I was thinking.